# C# - Indexer at its meaningful application

Tags: c#, language-features

I understand ***indexer enable us to access a collection within a class as though the class
itself were an array***.

Suppose we are developing a project ,where do we fit the real pratical usage (example may help) of such indexers ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look to almost any of the collection classes in the framework for an example.  If I were to retrieve an item from a hashtable in a language without an indexer, I would use syntax like:

```
object o = table.getvalue(key);
```

where an indexer allows somewhat simpler syntax:

```
object o = table[key];
```

(purposely ignoring typing/generics issues in the samples above)

Answer (score 5):

You have several examples in the generic collections of the framework itself. Dictionary is a pretty good example:

```
Dictionary<string, User> Users;

Users["Jorge"].ResetPassword();
```

That would be much elegant and simple than

```
Users.GetElementByKey("Jorge").ResetPassword();
```

Answer (score 3):

> indexer enables us to access a
>   collection within a class as though
>   the class itself were an array.

While that is true, you can write a class that **does not** have a permanent collection of items within itself, but still be capable to dynamically provide you with a calculated value when indexed. The data may be collected in real-time from the Internet, or any other data source - I imagine, as an example a class `SearchResults`, that I could use to obtain Google search results for a string like this: `Console.out.WriteLine(SearchResults["Stackoverflow"].count)`. It gathers the data **only when I'm asking for it** and return a collection of the retrieved items.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you are developing Microsoft .NET Framework for other developers to use (which is really a "real-world project"). You need to write a class that acts like an array but supports getting resized dynamically (the `List<T>` class). Without an indexer, you could write two methods to get and set elements:

```
public T get(int index) { ... }
public void set(int index, T value) { ... }
// (Java advocates: no offense intended)
```

Assume a user of your library wants to increment the second element. She'll have to write:

```
list.set(1, list.get(1) + 1);
```

With an indexer, the syntax is much simpler, more readable, and easier to understand:

```
list[1]++;
```

(similar arguments apply to things like `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`...)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the obvious application for using indexers are ... *(surprise)* Collections.

Such as:

- Lists:

  ```
  list[4]
  ```
- Hash tables:

  ```
  table["foo"]
  table[Color.Black]
  ```

Remember that indexers aren't restricted to integer arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If the collection is sorted, then the first and last elements may be useful for getting a minimum or maximum element.

In ASP.Net, there are several objects that use indexers like Application, Session, and Request.